# Treat undef in Perl's <=> operator as +inf instead of 0

Tags: sorting, perl, null

I have to sort some numbers with Perl. But some of the numbers are undefined. Perl's compare operator `<=>` treats `undef` as <strike>-inf</strike> 0. The result is, that the undefined numbers are at the beginning:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper(sort {$a <=> $b} 3, undef, 2, 1);'
$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR2 = 1;
$VAR3 = 2;
$VAR4 = 3;
```

I want them to occur at the end, because they represent new items, which should be added at the end. This means I am looking for a way to change the way Perl treats `undef`. In my case `undef` should be treated as +inf instead of <strike>-inf</strike> 0. I came up with the following expression.

```
($a <=> $b) * ((defined $a)*2-1) * ((defined $b)*2-1)
```

Is it always correct or did I miss anything?

And is there an easier way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 5):

In fact, Perl treats `undef` as 0 in numeric contexts, and warns about that (why there's no `-w` in your one-liner?). You can use the defined-or operator to handle it:

```
sort { ($a // 'Inf') <=> ($b // 'Inf') } 3, undef, 2, 1
```

You need Perl v5.10+ for it to work, in older versions, you have to be more verbose:

```
(defined $a ? $a : 'Inf')
```

Comment: I have Perl 5.8.4 here and using `defined` in the conditional operator has no effect on the sort order. Perl seems to understand 'Inf' but treats it as zero: http://pastebin.com/VAAP4dMw

Comment: @ceving: You must have mis-coded it. It should look like `sort { ( defined $a ? $a : 'Inf' ) <=> ( defined $b ? $b : 'Inf' ) } 3, undef, 2, 1`

Answer (score 2):

`$a <=> $b` will warn under warnings when one or both of variables is `undef`.

Thus, you can use short circuiting with `||` (high precedence OR operator), which will compare them only when both variables are defined (first two expressions evaluate to false),

```
sort { !defined($a)*1 || !defined($b)*-1 || $a <=> $b }
```

output

```
$VAR1 = 1;
$VAR2 = 2;
$VAR3 = 3;
$VAR4 = undef;
```

Comment: I think the result must be 0, if both are undefined.

Comment: @ceving you can `my ($da,$db) = map {defined} $a,$b; ($da || $db)*1 && (!$da*1 || !$db)*-1 || $a <=> $b)` for correctness, but sort result will not change.